# Lock screen turns monitor off right away 19.04

Tags: 19.04, lock-screen

When I lock the screen manually (or automatically) it turns off the monitor right away within 1-2 seconds! Why is that? There is no option to change this. What can I do about it? It's unreal.

Comment: I wish I had this problem. Mine doesn't turn off all.